# Permutations of a list with constraints python

Tags: python, list, combinatorics

I am desperately trying to get all the permutations of a list while enforcing position assignment constraints.
I have a list [1,2,3,4,5,6] (6 is just an example, I would like to find something that could work with every lenght) and I want to find all the lists of lenght 3 (also an example) with the following constraints :

- position 1 can be occupied by numbers 1 and 2
- position 2 can be occupied by numbers 1,2 and 3
- position 3 can be occupied by numbers 2,3 and 4
- repetions of a same number are not allowed

That would give these lists : *[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,2],[1,3,4],[2,1,3],[2,3,4],[2,1,4]*

[For those interested, what I am  trying to implement is what is explained pages 5 and 6 of this paper](http://www.mit.edu/~hamsa/pubs/BalakrishnanChandranGNC06.pdf)

Comment: So you want the *product* then of those numbers (`itertools.product([1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4])`), with a little unique number filtering?

Comment: The pseudocode for this appears on page 8 of that pdf, doesn't it?

Comment: No actually in page 8 it's another code aiming to find the shortest path that links the first node to the last. I had tried to generate manually the cartesian product and then remove the elements that I didn't want but that was endless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the `product()` of those subsets:

```
from itertools import product

for combo in product([1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]):
    if len(set(combo)) == 3:
        print(combo)
```

or as a list comprehension:

```
[combo for combo in product([1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]) if len(set(combo)) == 3]
```

Output:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [combo for combo in product([1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]) if len(set(combo)) == 3]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```